# welcome.blade.php show blank in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

```
enter code herewhen i try to this url then i got blank page not show default welcome.blade.php also
```

http://localhost/laravelpro2/mysite/public/

my project structure

laravelpro2-
     "mysite"
        --"app"
        --bootstrap
        --config
        --database
        --public
        --resources
        --storage
        --storage
        --tests
        --vendor
     vendor

Comment: Consider editing your question, because it's untintelligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal and:

```
cd path/to/your/laravelpro2
sudo chmod -R 755 storage/
sudo chmod -R 755 bootstrap/
```

if you have updated from laravel 5 to laravel 5.1 you should too:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe U R using mac or linux because same thing happen to me when I was using mac

Its because we have to change the accessibility in mac

use **terminal** and go inside **laravelpro2** folder and run following commands

```
sudo chmod -R o+w storage/
sudo chmod -R o+w bootstrap/
```

If it ask password just enter Yr login password and its done.

What it's doing is changing permission to read, write and update